# Permission iam.serviceAccounts.setIamPolicy is required to perform this operation on service account

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have below terraform script, to create a new service account and make it owner.
The scripts creates the service account, but it will throw an error on assigning role

```
resource "google_service_account" "pci_api_service_account" {
  account_id   = "pci-api"
  display_name = "Api"
  project      = var.project_id
}

resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "pci_api_owner_binding" {
  # service_account_id = "projects/pcb-poc-pci/serviceAccounts/infra-admin-sa@pcb-poc-pci.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  service_account_id = google_service_account.pci_api_service_account.name
  role   = "roles/owner"
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.pci_api_service_account.email}"
  depends_on = [
    google_service_account.pci_api_service_account
  ]
}
```

and I already autheticated with `infra-admin-sa` service account by running

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --project=pcb-poc-pci --key-file ~/sa/pcb-poc-pci-test-sa-94aa6c81d650.json
```

When I run `terragrunt apply` I get this error for the second script

> Error: Error applying IAM policy for service account 'projects/pcb-poc-pci/serviceAccounts/pci-api@pcb-poc-pci.iam.gserviceaccount.com': Error setting IAM policy for service account 'projects/pcb-poc-pci/serviceAccounts/pci-api@pcb-poc-pci.iam.gserviceaccount.com': googleapi: Error 403: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.setIamPolicy is required to perform this operation on service account projects/pcb-poc-pci/serviceAccounts/pci-api@pcb-poc-pci.iam.gserviceaccount.com., forbidden

These are the Roles of that service account
[image]

Based on google doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#iam.serviceAccountAdmin) and the error message, Service Account Admin should be enough, which my service account already have

[image]

Not sure what I missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

seems command line was not picking the correct credential/service account although I used `gcloud auth activate-service-account` command.

so I added this to my script

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = file(var.service_account_file_path)
  project     = var.project_id
}
```

and now it's working fine

### Solution 2

as per @John Hansley comments below

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=fullpath.json
```

then terraform will be picking that service account file and scripts will run successfully.

This method is preferred since less issue in CICD pipeline and other deveopers, to set terraform variables

Comment: The command `gcloud auth activate-service-account` sets up credentials for the CLI (gcloud). That command does not setup credentials for applications, APIs, etc. Your answer is correct and I prefer your method. Another recommended method is to set the environment variable to point to the service account JSON file: `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=fullpath.json`

Comment: For the problem in your question, you previously setup the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` or you executed the command `gcloud auth application-default login`. Check how you have the CLI and environment setup so that you do not run into problems in the future. Both of those methods setup ADC (Application Default Login). Terraform will use ADC for finding credentials if you do not specify a service account in the Terraform code.

Comment: @JohnHanley yes, you are right, I juts checked with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ` and is working too

Comment: In my previous comment I meant "Application Default Credentials" and not "Application Default Login".